# After sign in, redirect to authenticated root path

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

My problem is pretty straightforward, After a user signs in I want the system to bring them to the "Authenticated Root Path". Is there an idiom for this sort of thing. I'm doing lots of googling and I can't find anything on this topic.

Here is my SignIn.vue file:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      errorMessage: ""
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit: function () {
      axios.post('/user_token', {
        auth: {
          email: this.$refs.user_email.value,
          password: this.$refs.user_password.value
        }
      }).then(response => {
        this.$store.commit("LOGIN_SUCCESS", response)
      }).catch(error => {
        var err = error.response.data.errors
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Right now after a successful login the path just stays on the `/sign_in` path. I want it to change to an authenticated root path. How can I do this?

I understand that I'm not posting something testable but I really can't seem to find a way forward on this, so I'm looking for any help I can get on this. Thank You!

Comment: Using vue-router? If so, you want [navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html). If not, well, I recommend you do ;)

Comment: Yes I'm using vue-router. I'll look into navigation guards.

Comment: Cool. You'll want `this.$router.push('/authenticated/root/path')` (or something like that) to change the URL after sign-in

Comment: @Phil The Navigation guards are cool and I've actually implemented a beforeEach implementation. But I'm not seeing a clear example of a "root authenticated" path.

Comment: Well, the _authenticated_ routes will be behind a navigation guard that presumably checks the store for a valid authentication session. I've implemented this in the past by adding a `public: true` [route meta property](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/meta.html) on public routes. The `beforeEach` guard can then check the route for this property and if it is not set, redirect to `/sign_in` if there's no session. This is all a bit too broad for a single StackOverflow question though

Comment: True. Thank you for the help though. It makes a bit more sense now. I at least know where to dig in.

Comment: Found an example on [GitHub](https://github.com/PaperCutSoftware/dust-ui/blob/master/src/router/index.js)